# How to make column as a row in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot-table

How can I make columns QuotedReal and Rated as part of the value of 'ActualStatus' column?

```
select
        EffectiveDate,
        ActualStatus,
        SUM(case when ActualStatus = 'Bound' then 1 
                 when ActualStatus = 'Declined' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Quoted' then 1 
                 when ActualStatus = 'Not Taken Up' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Indication' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Submitted' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Lost' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Indicated' then 1             
        else 0 end) as CountActual,
        SUM(Quoted) as QuotedReal,
        SUM(Case when QuotedPremium is not null then 1 else 0 end) as Rated
from #Olegggg
group by EffectiveDate,
        ActualStatus
```

This is what I have now:

[image]

But I need something like that:

[image]

Comment: Instead of pictures can you post ddl for the table and sample data as inserts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to use a UNION to join the 3 record sets together..

```
select      EffectiveDate,
            ActualStatus,
            COUNT(*) as CountActual
from        #Olegggg
where       ActualStatus IN ('Bound','Declined',...'Indicated')
group by    EffectiveDate,
            ActualStatus

union all 
select      EffectiveDate,
            'Quoted Real',
            SUM(Quoted)
from        #Olegggg
group by    EffectiveDate

union all 
select      EffectiveDate,
            'Rated',
            COUNT(QuotedPremium)
from        #Olegggg
group by    EffectiveDate
```

Answer (score 1):

"JamieD" your solution is simple and correct except for the fact that

1.ActualStatus will not be used in group for "Rated" and "QuotedReal" .It should only be grouped and aggregated by the EffectiveDate to have one row per date.

2. No need to have "union all" as we do not have any duplicate data to pull.

   ```
   select      EffectiveDate,
               ActualStatus,
               COUNT(*) as CountActual
    from        #Olegggg
   where       ActualStatus IN ('Bound','Declined',...'Indicated')
   group by    EffectiveDate,
           ActualStatus
   union 
   select      EffectiveDate,
          'Quoted Real',
           SUM(Quoted)
   from        #Olegggg
   group by    EffectiveDate,
      //removed ActualStatus
   union 
     select      EffectiveDate,
               'Rated',
                COUNT(QuotedPremium)
    from        #Olegggg
     group by    EffectiveDate,
       //removed ActualStatus
   ```

Comment: It might be relevant tot get into the use of the DISTINCT operator SELECT DISTINCT EffectiveDate, 'Quoted Real', SUM(Quoted) from #Olegggg

Comment: Yes, that should give same output as group by

Comment: "No need to have "union all" as we do not have any duplicate data to pull."  UNION ALL is significantly less costly than UNION.  If you know you can't possibly have duplicates between your sets, UNION ALL is the appropriate operator.

Comment: @rmehra76 SELECT DISTINCT must never produce a result set which includes more than one instance of a value in the column on which DISTINCT has been applied to.

Comment: @russ , I did not get you .Where have i used DISTINCT in this post?

Comment: @rmehra76 Ah no, I wasn't saying you had used it, in fact, I did. I was just coming up with a possible rule for DISTINCT...it's OK, just an idea.